maximum number of edges in a planar graph on 11 vertces with no 5 cycle
It can be checked systematically that the result
ex$_P (n,C_5 )$ ≤ $(12n−33)/5$ holds for n ∈ {11, 12, 13} (this turns out to be not as onerous as
it might at first appear!)
How to compute maximum number of edges for a planar graph with 11 vertices with no 5 cycle systematically?
